# spring batch read from database and post to mqueue

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jms

I need to read records from the database and write it to jms queue. I started using spring, but I have no clue on how to do it programmatically.

Can anyone provide pointers in it? like a sample application or any tutorial.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Google for Spring Batch Examples reading from a database and writing to a message que.   It would align very well for that.

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers :

**Reader**

To read a database you can use a `JdbcBatchItemReader` or a `JdbcCursorItemReader`. There are actual examples in the official Spring Batch documentation : http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html

**Writer**

To write into queues you can use a `JmsItemWriter` or an `AmqpItemWriter`. These use a `JmsTemplate`. There are less examples available but you will be able to find some on Google.